# How do you debug a stored procedure in a Microsoft SQL Server that's been called from a seperate java program?

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, intellij-idea

I have a java program which at one point submits a query to my SQL server that triggers a stored procedure. I would like to debug this procedure when it's called by the java program so that I can

- Check that different combinations of parameters it receives are what I expect
- Check the procedure behaves exactly as I would expect with a given set of parameters

I know I can debug the procedure on its own, via SQL Server Manager, but this wouldn't let me debug it running in tandem with the java program.

Is there a way to be able to debug this SQL procedure at runtime with my java program?

Answer (score 1):

I would run SQL Server Profiler and and run your Java program.  SQL Server profiler will let you see the stored procedure that will run with the params that were passed in.

Comment: This looks promising, but the material I found on it doesn't explain whether this trace that it saves will let you see the whole state for each step of the process? I have a lot of scripts that can have a range of parameters passed to them, being able to see quickly and easily the state of everything at any point in the execution process is very important. Do you know if it has this functionality?

Answer (score 1):

There is a debugger that is available for SQL server. See https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Cc646008(v=SQL.105).aspx

Comment: As far as I'm aware you can only debug code that's currently being written in the code editor? There's no way to link this code to the actual stored procedure that will be executed by the server when my java code calls it. That means I cannot debug a live process, in the same way I could if I ran a java program in debug mode on IntelliJ.